# How to get {mailing.viewUrl} & {contact.checksum} to work together?

Tags: tokens, checksum

So, both tokens work fine when sending mailings..  however, whenever I view the mailing in the browser by using the {mailing.viewUrl} token.. any url I have in the mailing that uses the {contact.checksum} token breaks.

> Instead of a checksum, I get this in the urls.. cs=invalidChecksum

Is there a way to get those tokens to work together.. or is there a way to create another url to view mailings in the browser without loosing the checksums?

Comment: Are you using Mosaico/Flexmailer?  Or "classic" CiviMail?